# I want to load package name data in PackageAuditData. Tried with System variable with drived column but not work in ssis

Tags: ssis

I want to load package name data in PackageAuditData. Tried with System variable with drived column but not work in ssis.I Have 5 packages inside a solution. I want all package name and want to load all package name into the table.Please help me?

Comment: Hi Manisha , I have given a solution for your problem ,could you please check and let me know ?

Comment: if you are ok with my solution then please up Vote as a answer and click at the OK mark ..

Answer (score 0):

**Very good question!**

First of all go in the `SSISDB` `database` and run below query ,you can get all the `package` name inside a `SSIS solution` or 'Project'.

```
DECLARE @pakage_Id VARCHAR(500)

SET @pakage_Id = (
        SELECT project_id
        FROM [SSISDB].[internal].[projects]
        WHERE name LIKE '%YOUR_PROJECT_NAME%'
        )

SELECT DISTINCT Package_name
FROM [SSISDB].[internal].[executables]
WHERE project_id = @pakage_Id
```

Now you call all the package name in variable after creating a **connection manage**r for `SSISDB` `database` and use it where you want.

I hope this is what for which you are looking for ....